# Ajax calls are slower to controller in physically different file

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

While trying to speed up some ajax calls in one of our MVC pages, I encountered some strange behavior which I can't really explain. I have some ajax calls being made every N seconds for polling some statistics.

It seems like ajax calls being made to a controller in a physically different file are substantially slower than similar calls being made to a controller in the same physical file as where the view originates from.

See my simplified examples:

**Situation 1: Only 1 file**

*FooController.cs*

```
namespace FooBar.Areas.FooArea.Controllers
{
    [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
    public class FooTestController: _BaseController
    {
        public JsonResult GetStats()
        {
            try
            {
                var req = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.GET };
                req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                req.AddParameter("apikey", /*APIKEY*/);

                var client = new RestClient(/*STATSURL*/);
                var response = client.Execute(req);

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return Json(new { success = true, content = response.Content });
                else
                    return Json(new { success = false });
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }

        public JsonResult GetAgents()
        {
            var req = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.GET };
            req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            req.AddParameter("apikey", /*APIKEY*/);

            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient(/*AGENTSURL*/);
                var response = client.Execute(req);

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return Json(new { success = true, content = response.Content });
                else
                    return Json(new { success = false });
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }
    }

    public class FooController : _BaseController
    {
        // VIEW OF THE PAGE MAKING THE AJAX REQUESTS
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Title = "Home";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Situation 2: 2 seperate files in same folder**

*FooController.cs*

```
namespace FooBar.Areas.FooArea.Controllers
{
    public class FooController: _BaseController
    {
        // VIEW OF THE PAGE MAKING THE AJAX REQUESTS
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Title = "Home";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

*FooAjaxController.cs*

```
namespace FooBar.Areas.FooArea.Controllers
{
    [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
    public class FooAjaxController: _BaseController
    {
        public JsonResult GetStats()
        {
            try
            {
                var req = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.GET };
                req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                req.AddParameter("apikey", /*APIKEY*/);

                var client = new RestClient(/*STATSURL*/);
                var response = client.Execute(req);

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return Json(new { success = true, content = response.Content });
                else
                    return Json(new { success = false });
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }

        public JsonResult GetAgents()
        {
            var req = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.GET };
            req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            req.AddParameter("apikey", /*APIKEY*/);

            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient(/*AGENTSURL*/);
                var response = client.Execute(req);

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return Json(new { success = true, content = response.Content });
                else
                    return Json(new { success = false });
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In both situations, the ajax calls are made from jQuery as follows:

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: // URL TO ACTION DEPENDING ON SITUATION,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (result)
    {
        if (result.success)
        {
            var content = JSON.parse(result.content);
            console.log(content);
        }
    }
});
```

Now, the response times from the ajax requests for both situations are as follows, with situation 1 being displayed on the left and situation 2 on the right:

[image]
[image]

So, as you can see the average time of a call made to `GetStats()` and `GetAgents()` in situation 1 is **52.8 ms** and **53.8 ms** respectively.

However, in situation 2, the average time of the calls is **486.8 ms** and **529.9 ms**.

My question now is: how can it be that ajax calls made to actions are on average almost 10 times slower when those actions reside in a controller in a physically different file, than when those actions reside in a controller which shares the same physical file as the file rendering the view in the first place?

Is it because the file containing the action to render the view is already loaded and kept in memory, while the seperate file, as in in situation 2, is opened and closed every time the action is called? Or is something more sinister going on?

Comment: I suspect the `OTHER STUFF` might be needed in order to fully answer this question - either that or narrow down further until you can post a complete example displaying this behaviour.

Comment: @AntP Fair enough. I've added the `OTHER STUFF`, although I didn't think it would made a difference, because the actions in both situations do exactly the same thing (calling a third party URL to get some statistics/agents).

Comment: Controllers with related classes in different files get compiled into a DLL, so the process doesn't really know the difference either way...  sounds like something else is going on?

Comment: @BrianMains That makes sense. I will have to research further about what's going on then. When I know more, I'll report back!

Answer (score 0):

You shared most of the code but not `_BaseController.cs`

1. On each request, MVC gets the controller using dependency injection.
   [speculation] MVC may store the most recently-used controller, returning the same one several times. However if you are switching controllers, perhaps it creates a new one each time.
2. Perhaps there is some very slow code in the `_BaseController` default constructor - perhaps database queries. It sounds unlikely but has happened in my experience.

Taken together, these things would cause the slowdown you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So far, I haven't had the time to really investigate this any further, but it is something I still intend to do. Point 1 you make could make sense, but is hard to proof. Point 2 isn't really the issue I think, because both situations make use of the same _BaseController. I could, however, try to make a setup that doesn't depend on any _BaseController.